# Reading obj/array to html

Tags: javascript, html

Quick question.. Im trying to make my html read name property of my object/array, and Im failing.
I have html:

```
  <li ng-repeat="i in data">
        <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
   </li>
```

and I have lib that is:

```
data = [{"name":"a","code":"12"},{"name":"b","code":"331"},{"name":"c","code":"1231"}]
```

my html li "ng-repeat="i in data" makes right amount of lists(3). But my h3 doesnt print the names.. what am i missing?

Comment: I think you have a typo. I think it should be `i.name`, not `data.name`

Comment: @jsookiki yeah Thanks! unbelivable

Answer (score 1):

```
 <li ng-repeat="i in data">
        <h3>{{i.name}}</h3>
 </li>


... scope context
$scope.data = [{"name":"a","code":"12"},{"name":"b","code":"331"},{"name":"c","code":"1231"}]
```

Comment: thank you i feel like an idiot now. cant believe what i was missing:)

Comment: You should mark this as the answer seeing as it answered your question.